# merging data frame by column AND row

Tags: r, merge, row

I have a two data set that shares similar aspects, for instance dataset A

```
name    year    region
Jane    1980    1
Jane    1981    2
Mike    1980    1
Mike    1985    4
Bob     1980    NA
Bob     1981    1
```

and dataset B

```
year    1   2   3   4   5
1980    12  44  76  108 140
1981    55  77  99  121 143
1982    56  76  96  116 136
1983    56  43  30  17  4
```

I want to create a new column in the first data set called "`income`" which incorporates the numbers in the second dataset according to year and columns 1-5. For instance, since Bob in year 1980 was in region 5, the corresponding `income` would be 140. If there is no match, I want `income` to be `NA`.

So far I tried

```
which(A$year==B$year & A$region==rownames(B)[2:6])
```

but I don't think this works.

I also want to add that there aren't matches for all data points, there are NAs for the region variable in data set A, and the number of years in data set B do not cover all of the years in data set A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative since Joran is making me work....

Create a `matrix` of your incomes.

```
b <- as.matrix(B[-1])
rownames(b) <- B[,1]
```

Use `match` to match "year" from the first `data.frame` with the `rownames` of this new matrix. We can create a matrix with that as our first column (row index) and "region" from your original `data.frame` as the second column (column index).

```
cbind(match(A$year, rownames(b)), A$region)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    2    2
# [3,]    1    1
# [4,]    2    4
# [5,]    1    5
# [6,]    2    1
```

We can use that to extract the relevant data from matrix "b", and add it to your original `data.frame`.

```
A$income <- b[cbind(match(A$year, rownames(b)), A$region)]
A
#   name year region income
# 1 Jane 1980      1     12
# 2 Jane 1981      2     77
# 3 Mike 1980      1     12
# 4 Mike 1981      4    121
# 5  Bob 1980      5    140
# 6  Bob 1981      1     55
```

---

This assumes we are starting with:

```
A <- read.table(text = "name    year    region
Jane    1980    1
Jane    1981    2
Mike    1980    1
Mike    1981    4
Bob     1980    5
Bob     1981    1",header = TRUE,sep = "")

B <- read.table(text = "year    1   2   3   4   5
1980    12  44  76  108 140
1981    55  77  99  121 143
1982    56  76  96  116 136
1983    56  43  30  17  4",header = TRUE,sep = "",check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this code! I have one problem though - since not all of data points match, there are number of NAs after I do cbind(match(A$year, rownames(b)), A$region) on the whole data set, and when I try to extract this from b, I get an error "subscript out of bounds". Would there be a way to extract the one that I found but leave the rest as NAs?

Comment: @Rusuer9000, even with your edit, both my answer and Joran's work. Can you see if you can recreate a small dataset (in a reproducible manner, like we have done in these answers) that demonstrate the problem/error? Thanks.

Comment: I figured out the problem - the matrix after doing cbind was a character matrix, which I had to turn it into numeric before extracting from b. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is my third attempt to provide `sqldf` solutions to data transformation problems in the last couple of weeks. No love yet. We'll see what people think this time...

Using the data from Joran's answer:

```
require(sqldf)

sqldf('select 
          a.name
          ,a.year
          ,a.region
          ,case 
            when region = 1 then b.X1
            when region = 2 then b.X2
            when region = 3 then b.X3
            when region = 4 then b.X4
            when region = 5 then b.X5
          end income
        from a
          join b
            on a.year= b.year')
```

Here I am "melting" the data using a standard SQL case statement.

`sqldf` does require that I prefix the region columns in `b` with an X as the database engine running under the package forces non-integer field names.

Comment: ill spread the sqldf love, although the statement is pretty verbose. I'd get lazy and start throwing `paste`s in there

Comment: @Manetheran, I agree its a bit more verbose and with many more "wide" fields, we would definitely want to cut down on the hard coding through `paste`, etc. I am about to get on a flight but might edit this to that effect in a bit. That said, what SQL lacks in verbosity, it tends to make up for with transparency.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to convert your second data set from wide to long format. This can be done rather easily using **reshape2** and **plyr**:

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)

b <- read.table(text = "year    1   2   3   4   5
1980    12  44  76  108 140
1981    55  77  99  121 143
1982    56  76  96  116 136
1983    56  43  30  17  4",header = TRUE,sep = "",check.names = FALSE)

a <- read.table(text = "name    year    region
Jane    1980    1
Jane    1981    2
Mike    1980    1
Mike    1981    4
Bob     1980    5
Bob     1981    1",header = TRUE,sep = "")

b <- melt(b,id.vars = "year")
b <- rename(b,c("variable" = "region"))

merge(a,b,all.x = TRUE)
```

Depending on which type of join you want, you could use either `all.y = TRUE` or `all = TRUE` in `merge`.

Comment: Could you elaborate little more on what melt does and what "variable" = "region" would mean? I tried the melt command but it did not change anything.

Comment: @Rusuer9000, `melt` transforms the data into a "long" form. `"variable" = "region"` just renames the "variable" variable that is created when you melt a `data.frame` to "region".

Comment: Joran, you can save having to load a package just for `rename` by using the `variable.name` argument in `melt`: `melt(b, id.vars="year", variable.name="region")`.

Answer (score 1):

Since joran and Ananda are taking all the good options, here's a ridiculous one:

```
a$income <- 
  mapply(function(ro,co) b[ro,co], match(a$year,b$year), as.character(a$region))

#  name year region income
#1 Jane 1980      1     12
#2 Jane 1981      2     77
#3 Mike 1980      1     12
#4 Mike 1981      4    121
#5  Bob 1980      5    140
#6  Bob 1981      1     55
```

(This uses the data from joran's answer.)

Comment: I think you're using data from my answer and @joran's answer, but +1 nevertheless :-)

Comment: My point was that while your `mapply` is referring to `a/b`, you're assigning it to some object named `A`...

Comment: Oh crud balls... you have to be more explicit with me - it's been a long year! ;-)

Comment: Hi, I edited my question a bit - I don't think the code works when there are NAs after doing cbind?

Comment: @Rusuer9000 - joran's answer will work just fine with NA values. Mine, not so much.